# Angular Material 2 Datatable Pagination with AngularFire2 Firestore Datasource

Tags: angular, firebase, datatable, google-cloud-firestore, angular-material2

I've populated an observable array/MatTableDataSource in my controller with data from an 'expenses' collection in firestore, and I want to be able to use the angular material 2 pagination method on this, but can't find any documentation/tutorials online that give any indication as to how this would be done.

My controller is set up like this currently, but the attempt at pagination is not working:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { Expense } from '../expenseModel';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-expense-list',
  templateUrl: './expense-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./expense-list.component.scss']
})

export class ExpenseListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  //    tableColumns = [ 'id', 'reference', 'date', 'description', 'category', 'type', 'nominal', 'value', 'taxCode', 'tax', 'total' ];
  tableColumns = [ 'id' ];

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  expenses = new MatTableDataSource(this.expenses);

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.expenses = this.db.collection('/expenses', ref => ref.orderBy('id')).valueChanges();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.expenses.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  viewExpense(row) {
    console.log('viewExpense(' + row.id + '): ', row);
  }

}
```

Comment: Please post html for this controller/component.  Are you using mat-table?  Have you read through.. https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples  Also, see example on stackblitz... https://stackblitz.com/angular/jyqjropxjod

Comment: Yes, I'm using the mat-table element. As I said in the question, I have read through the documentation, and the links you have posted are irrelevant to the given scenario, given they do not cover firebase/firestore collection pagination in material datatables

Answer (score -1):

Because I am curious, I will put together a sample stackblitz shortly, and post up here when done.  The following is my "approach"...

In my html, add the paging, like:

```
<mat-paginator [length]="length"
    [pageSize]="pageSize"
    [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
    (page)="getExpenses($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

In my component, add paging event to go get a page of data, like:

```
length;
pageSize = 10;  // set default to 10
pageSizeOptions = [5, 10, 25, 100];

constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.getExpenses();
}

getExpenses(event?: PageEvent) {
    this.expenses = this.db.collection('/expenses')
        .orderBy('id')
        .startAt(event.pageIndex)
        .limit(event.pageSize)
        .get();
    this.length = this.expenses.size;
}
```

UPDATE:  Research I have been doing towards implementing a solution of paging via Angular Firestore lead me to [Simple Pagination With AngularFire2](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/simple-firebase-pagination-with-angularfire2/)

Comment: I've just tried this and there were numerous errors, it doesn't look like a workable solution

Comment: I am working on a stackblitz that I will post when I have working...  it will demonstrate how to use firestore to suplly paginated data to the mat-table

Comment: I think this is the only approach we have for paging. So every time the page index changes we have to pass the last key in that page to load the next page values. I am not sure how this approach works if we are using the server side sorting as well.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, and solved it putting everything inside ngOnInit method

component.ts

```
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name', 'status']
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.db.collection('users').valueChanges()
      .subscribe(users => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(users);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      })
  }
```

template.html

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="w-100">

    ...
  </table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```